# Chrome devices devTools different from actual devices for media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to build a responsive website for ipad and mobile as well. 
This is the [Link](https://eliijahh.github.io/weather-report/index.html)  if you want to check it out.

Anyway, when I use the devTools in chrome for checking out the layouts on the Galaxy S5, then the landscape view is all good. When I check it on the actual device, then the height seems to be a bit less, and some parts of the website are actually cut out. Probably due to some parts of the device not being accounted for in the height.

Screenshot from the chrome dev tools, using the width and height of the S4 mini viewport when in landscape mode:
[image: Screenshot from the chrome dev tools, using the width and height of the S4 mini viewport when in landscape mode]

Screenshot from the actual device in landscape mode
[image: Screenshot from the actual device in landscape mode]

So the questions are:

1. How do I actually use the devTools in Chrome to get a precise
   representation?
2. Do I need to actually account for browser size in the @media (min-width: whatever px) query?
3. Is my question wrong from another perspective I haven't considered? Am I missing something?